# select query char numeric id to order by desc

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I have example data

```
SMMP022011304196
SMMP022011304199    
SMMP022011304197    
SMMP022011304193
SMMP022011304195    
SMMP022011304198    
SMMP022011304192    
SMMP0220113041910   
SMMP022011304191
SMMP022011304194
```

If I use `SELECT myfield from mytable order by myfield DESC`
I got result like this

```
SMMP022011304199    
SMMP022011304198    
SMMP022011304197    
SMMP022011304196    
SMMP022011304195    
SMMP022011304194    
SMMP022011304193    
SMMP022011304192    
SMMP0220113041910   
SMMP022011304191
```

Please help to make result like this :

```
SMMP0220113041910   
SMMP022011304199    
SMMP022011304198    
SMMP022011304197    
SMMP022011304196    
SMMP022011304195    
SMMP022011304194    
SMMP022011304193    
SMMP022011304192    
SMMP022011304191
```

Comment: Is the format always like that (ie, 4 characters followed by numerics)? Reason for your sort order as it is, is that MySQL has sorted it as a character string rather than a character string followed by a numeric. Hence you would need to split it into the character part and the numeric part, cast the numeric part to a number field and then sort by both fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sort by LENGTH of field and then for values with equal length:

```
SELECT myfield from mytable order by 
LENGTH(myfield) DESC,
myfield DESC
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cffe5/3)

Comment: This is a clever and efficient way to do it. The only flaw I can see is if the numeric part has an extra leading 0, in which case the length increases but the value of the numeric part doesn't. However this is quite likely irrelevant for most cases  where such a sort is required.

Answer (score 1):

If the data always have SMMP in front, you could use below:

```
ORDER BY LPAD(REPLACE(myfield,'SMMP',''),15,'0') desc;
```

The logic for this method is to ignore the 4 char in front and only sort the numeric figure behind.

Comment: How if not always SMMP in front of my data ?

Comment: Then does your data always begin with 4 character in front?

Comment: Just notice Kickstart solution. You could refer to @Kickstart solution if your data always has 4 char in front.

Answer (score 1):

Following my earlier comment, sort as follows:-

```
SELECT myfield
FROM mytable
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(myfield, 1, 4) DESC, cast(SUBSTRING(myfield, 5) AS unsigned) DESC
```

Note this only works if your field is of a fixed format with 4 characters followed by numerics

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine.
Below code is work for SQL Server 2008 R2 :

```
SELECT 
   myfield  
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY 
    LEN(myfield) DESC 
    ,myfield DESC
```